# PHP/MySQL - How to save results to another array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im stuck in my code. I don't know how to save result that is stored in array to another array. Can you help me ? Thank you very much.

PHP:

```
$sql_curr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tr_Prices WHERE tr_code = '$acode'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_cur)){
   if($row['price'] != ''){
      // there should be array with results if not empty column
   }

}

$Arr_Curr = array(

    //there should be results from previous array as 'example' => 'example'

);
```

Comment: So simply in while loop do `$Arr_Curr[] = $row['price']`. Also, `mySql_*` is deprecated, don't use it. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO

Comment: Why not just check for it in query itself? `select * from tr_Prices where tr_code = '$acode' and price is not null`

Comment: @Steve true good option

Comment: @user3105439 Also use PDO instead of `mysql_*` it's deprecated. Right now your code is prone to sql injection. http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: @Steve what about mysql_real_escape_string() before insert it elsewhere ?

Comment: @user3105439 Forget about `mysql_*` functions. It's flawed by design.

Answer (score 0):

> $sql_curr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tr_Prices WHERE tr_code = '$acode'");
>   $newarr=array();
>
> while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_cur)){
>   if($row['price'] != ''){
>   $new_arr[]=$row;
>   }
>
> }
>
> );